# javascript Datepicker Popup Calendar not working in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am working on  **MVC** project , I want to use the **date picker** popup calendar. But it is not working. Here is my code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            yearOffset: -15, 
            lang: 'en',
            timepicker: false,
            format: 'm/d/Y',
            formatDate: 'Y/m/d',
            // minDate: '1940/01/02', // yesterday is minimum date
            // maxDate: '2000/01/02' // and tommorow is maximum date calendar
        });
    });
</script>
```

VIEW

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label class="control-label" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px;margin-top:6px;">
        Date Of Birth<b style=" color:#ff0000;">*</b>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3" style="left:-25px;">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.DOB, new { Class = "form-control ", placeholder = "Date of Birth", id = "datetimepicker", TextMode = "date", value = "01/11/1989", maxlength = "20", style = "width:175px;height:25px;font-size:small;" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.DOB)
</div>
```

Comment: What is not working? What errors are there in the browser console? And as you have been repeatedly told previously - its `@class="form-control"` and `TextMode="date"` is invalid and you should never set the `value` attribute (set the value of property `DOB` before you pass the model to the view)

Comment: yeah im pass the DOB in Model

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Are you getting any errors in Console?

Comment: no any errors, , not a showing popup

Comment: no console error, i think its script problem

Comment: Add your script in $(window).load(function() { }); and try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is that .NET MVC Helper methods replace the **id** attribute of the *Input text* to something it can track for its inner workings.

you can get the destined *id* by `HTML.idFor(f=> f.DOB);` in your `$('#datetimepicker')...` line.

Comment: Wrong. OP has included `new { id = "datetimepicker" }` so the input has `id="datetimepicker"` which is correctly selected using `$('#datetimepicker')` (and the `id` attribute has nothing to do with 'post-backs' - its added solely for use as a javascript selector)